# Strange incrementing of iterators when passing them as an argument

Tags: c++, iterator, arguments, increment

I immediately apologize for my terrible English :D

For my project, I need to analyze the obj file. I line-by-line read the file and  select data from a specific string using regular expressions.

```
regex regCoord("-?\\d+\.?\\d*");
sregex_iterator a(line.begin(), line.end(), regCoord);
```

I know for sure that 3 matches have been found and I want to use them right away. For example, output to the console or save to a structure

```
cout << line << endl;
cout << a++->str() << " " << a++->str() << " " << a->str() << endl;
```

But in this case, incrementing occurs in the reverse order, from left to right! And on the output I get not (1st element, 2nd element, 3rd element), but (2nd element, 1st element, 1st element). A similar problem occurs if I pass all three elements to the structure constructor.

```
Output:
v 0.151164 0.014830 -0.051720
0.014830 0.151164 0.151164
```

But if I loop through the elements or write output in three lines, the result will look normal. Likewise, if I fill a structure without using a constructor, and write to each of its fields separately.

```
cout << a++->str() << " ";
cout << a++->str() << " ";
cout << a->str() << endl;

Output:
v 0.151164 0.014830 -0.051720
0.151164 0.014830 -0.051720
```

Why can there be such a strange inverted argument handling? I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Order of evaluation of argument of function is unspecified.

Comment: See [eval order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order). C++17 guaranties the order you want Btw.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ouch ... Thank you)

Comment: Re: "my terrible English" -- not terrible at all. There's one spot where the word order is unusual, but it's all quite clear.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks to Google Translate :D